# Changing the battery of a Logitech M705 mouse

Tags: mouse, battery

Is it possible to change the battery on a Logitech M705 mouse? If so, how?

Comment: I don’t see why not; there is clearly an accessible battery compartment on the bottom. What is the problem?

Answer (score 3):

Yes... It's in their support pages [here](http://logitech-en-amr.custhelp.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/12691/session/L3RpbWUvMTM1NDYzMDE4MC9zaWQvVGM3YTVWY2w%3D), with a step by step walk through.